# Create ASP.NET WebForm .NET 6 VS 2022 based ASPX pages not razor

Tags: asp.net, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

How can we create ASP.NET WebForm .NET 6 VS 2022 based ASPX pages (*.aspx), not razor (*.cshtml)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

ASPX is from the WebForms (System.Web) part of the .NET Framework.  This area was not ported to .NET Core, or to newer versions of .NET (5+), and there are no plans to do so.

For a component-based web development framework, Blazor is the new Microsoft platform.  There is a migration guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/migration) which can serve as a starting point, but migrating will be an involved process.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can create WebForm project (with .aspx) in .NET 6.
You can use VS 2022 to create a WebForm project if you install .NET Framework 4.8.